# How can I make a segue not occur if a condition isn't met?

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I want to make a conditional segue between scenes so that it would only happen if a condition was met. The thing is when I tap the button that activates this segue, it performs the segue without caring about whether the condition was met or not. Here's the code:

```
@IBAction func goonbutton(sender: UIButton) {
    if textFieldRandomWord.text !=nil
    {
        performSegueWithIdentifier("firstsegue", sender: sender)
    } else {
        whateverLabel.text = "You didn't actually write anything."
    }
}
```

So I want the segue to occur only if textFieldRandomWord != nil. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure you want to test against nil?  Or do you actually need to test against the empty string, ""?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want to do is implement something like:

```
override func shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String, sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool {

    if identifier == "WhateverYourSegueIsNamed" { // you define it in the storyboard (click on the segue, then Attributes' inspector > Identifier

        if textFieldRandomWord.text.isEmpty == true {
            print("*** NOPE, segue wont occur")
            return false
        }
        else {
            print("*** YEP, segue will occur")
        }
    }

    // by default, transition
    return true
}
```

and I'm basing my answer on the great example can be seen [in this related question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25435875/981049)

Comment: Very helpful, but I still don't get the var segueShouldOccur. What is it exactly?

Comment: you actually don't need it, it was something I carried over from that other answer when I ported it specific for you.  :-)

Comment: ok, now I get it. But it reports an error telling that the method does not override any method from its superclass. If I remove "override", a long error text that mentions Objective-C appears. What should I do?

Comment: exactly. also a UITextFieldDelegate

Comment: does function completion work?  i.e. if you start typing "`func shouldPerformSegue`", will Xcode complete that function prototype for you?  I'm thinking you might simply have a typo.

Comment: solved. So I must put all this code inside the action of the button, do I? @MichaelDautermann

Comment: no, it should simply be a function within your UIViewController subclass.

Answer (score 1):

You're pretty close. You don't want to test against nil. Instead, you should test if the textField is empty.

```
if !textFieldRandomWord.text.isEmpty
{
  performSegueWithIdentifier("firstsegue", sender: sender)
}
else 
{
  whateverLabel.text = "You didn't actually write anything."
}
```

You might need to add an unwrap on textFieldRandomWord if it's an Optional, as outlets usually are.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that if the textfield is empty it isn't equal to nil, you can write this instead and it should work

```
@IBAction func goonbutton(sender: UIButton) {
    if textFieldRandomWord.text != ""
    {
        performSegueWithIdentifier("firstsegue", sender: sender)
    } else {
        whateverLabel.text = "You didn't actually write anything."
    }
}
```

writing an empty string ("") instead of nil