# How to progromatically stop actions segue swift

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

so I have multiple viewcontrollers in my project, and I perform an action segue from the first to the second when the button called `SignIn` is called. What I need to do, however, is stop this action segue from being performed, on a condition. For example, `if isThereAnError == true { write code to stop action segue }` I have looked all over apple documentation and stack overflow but to no prevail. Any and all help is greatly appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25113602/using-shouldperformseguewithidentifier-method-in-swift

Comment: Really? This is hard to find in the documentation? Really?

Answer (score 0):

UIViewController has a method called 'shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:sender:'. You can use this to stop segues from happening. In this case you'd use the following code:

Objective-C:

```
-(BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier
                                  sender:(id)sender{
   if([identifier isEqualToString:@"{YOUR_SEGUE_IDENTIFIER_HERE}"]){
      return NO;
   }
  return YES;
}
```

Swift:

```
func shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier(_ identifier: String,
                               sender sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool{
    if(identifier == "{YOUR_SEGUE_IDENTIFIER_HERE}"){
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate this, but where would I add in the condintions, like if  isthereAnError == true return false and what nort>